# how Block all cookies in webdriver chrome python

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium-webdriver

I searched a lot for the code to stop cookies and it didn't work
There are changes in the browser and the commands no longer work. I want a code that works at the moment

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

try this `prefs`

```
chrome_options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
# 1 to allow, 2 to block
prefs = {
  "profile.default_content_setting_values.cookies": 2,
  "profile.block_third_party_cookies": true
}
chrome_options.add_experimental_option("prefs",prefs)
driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options=chrome_options)
```